# UIPageViewController: App crashs when adding more than one view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to make tutorial screens for my app. I'm using the UIPageViewController. But when I add two ViewControllers my app crashes. Here's my code:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    //This is not final. Just for demo
    return _secondPage;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    //This is not final. Just for demo
    return _firstPage;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageControllers count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

@end
```

When I debug the App it crashes with this line of code:

```
 [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:_pages direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can you post the error on crash?

Comment: Are you certain that `self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];` is returning a `UIPageViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a wrong, or non-existent `ID` to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`: method you will get an exception and your app will terminate. Most likely this is what is happening.

The ID is under the `Identity Inspector` tab in `Interface Builder`. It's called `Storyboard ID`. You can give it any unique name that you want. The most important thing is to use this `ID` when instantiating a view controller. Otherwise your code will rise an exception.

Comment: When I only have one View Controller everything works fine. But when I add two my app chrashes.